# EnumDesktopWindows (C++) takes about 30 mins to find the desired open Window on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This problem occurs only on Windows 10. Works fine on other versions such as Windows 7.

On user action, I have following code to find out another open application window as:

```
void zcTarget::LocateSecondAppWindow( void )
{
    ghwndAppWindow = NULL;
    CString csQuickenTitleSearch = "MySecondApp";
    ::EnumDesktopWindows( hDesktop, MyCallback, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)csTitleSearch );
}
```

With callback functions as:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyCallback( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
   if ( ::GetWindowTextLength( hwnd ) == 0 )
   {
      return TRUE;
   }

   CString strText;
   GetWindowText( hwnd, strText.GetBuffer( 256 ), 256 );
   strText.ReleaseBuffer();

   if ( strText.Find( (LPCTSTR)lParam ) == 0 )
   {
      // We found the desired app HWND, so save it off, and return FALSE to
      // tell EnumDesktopWindows to stopping iterating desktop HWNDs.
      ghwndAppWindow = hwnd;

      return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
} // This is the line after which call is not returned for about 30 mins
```

This callback function mentioned above gets called for about 7 times, each time returning True. At this stage it finds own app window through which EnumDesktopWindows was invoked.

It returns True as expected, but then nothing happens for about 30 minutes. No debug points hit. The original running application is unresponsive at this point.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: please show [mcve]

Comment: 30 *minutes*? Who on earth waits 30 minutes to find out how long it takes?

Comment: I've seen a similar question not long ago -- seems that you have hit a window that doesn't bother responding to messages. Since `GetWindowText()` sends the `WM_GETTEXT` message internally, your thread gets stuck waiting for a response that will never come. I don't know of any workaround for this, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrédéricHamidi . That helps a lot. I was not sure which direction to go from here. I will get back if I find any workaround.

Comment: @nvoigt Anyone who can turn their attention to something else for 30 minutes while it runs.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  Indeed! Installer programs which change system environment variables sometimes run into a very similar issue. Typically they broadcast a message to tell every app to get the new environment variables. That can get hung on some non-responsive app.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Instead of using `GetWindowText()`, try using `SendMessageTimeout()` to send `WM_GETTEXT` directly and skip it if a timeout elapses.

Comment: @Remy, that's an excellent workaround :)

Comment: GetWindowText is designed to avoid problems with unresponsive windows.  It only sends the message if the window is in the same process.  Otherwise, it just pulls the caption from a well-known place.  So if there's an unresponsive process, it's this program.  Use Spy++ to confirm.

Comment: And from the description, the problem occurs _after_ GetWindowText finds the actual window (though I'm reading between the lines here).

Comment: The problem occurs when MyApp tries calling GetWindowText() on itself.
The documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:
However, if the target window is not responding and it belongs to the calling application, GetWindowText will cause the calling application to become unresponsive. - which makes sense in this case

Comment: Is the problem window in this process, but a different thread?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's all in the one main thread.

Comment: That should work then.  But if the call to EnumDesktopWindows is in the context of a message handler, you might be winding up with an unexpected recursion, perhaps you aren't handling this quite properly?

Comment: Attach a debugger while it's stalled, break into the program, and post the stack trace.  That should be pretty illuminating.  @Harry Johnston:  If it were a recursion problem, I'd expect a permanent hang or a stack overflow--it's not quite consistent with a 30-minute hang.

Comment: You are mixing ANSI string literals, `TCHAR`s, and API calls with generic text mappings. It's not clear, whether `GetWindowText(hwnd, strText.GetBuffer(256), 256)` copies a wide character string into a `CStringW`, an ANSI string into a `CStringA`, or winds up with a `CString` object whose `ReleaseBuffer`-call is left to deal with mismatching/unexpected character encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another path. Instead of going by Window name, looking for Process helps. Get process using process name, extract process id and get window handle.

```
void zcTarget::LocateSecondAppWindow( void )
 {
       PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
       entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
       HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

       if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
       {
          while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
          {
             if (_stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "myApp.exe") == 0)
             {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);               

                EnumData ed = { GetProcessId( hProcess ) };
                if ( !EnumWindows( EnumProc, (LPARAM)&ed ) &&
                   ( GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS ) ) {
                      ghwndQuickenWindow = ed.hWnd;
                }
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                break;
             }
          }
       }
       CloseHandle(snapshot);
}

       BOOL CALLBACK EnumProc( HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam ) {
       // Retrieve storage location for communication data
       zcmTaxLinkProTarget::EnumData& ed = *(zcmTaxLinkProTarget::EnumData*)lParam;
       DWORD dwProcessId = 0x0;
       // Query process ID for hWnd
       GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &dwProcessId );
       // Apply filter - if you want to implement additional restrictions,
       // this is the place to do so.
       if ( ed.dwProcessId == dwProcessId ) {
          // Found a window matching the process ID
          ed.hWnd = hWnd;
          // Report success
          SetLastError( ERROR_SUCCESS );
          // Stop enumeration
          return FALSE;
       }
       // Continue enumeration
       return TRUE;
    }
```